# Easy Way to See if Two Columns are One-to-One in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, one-to-one

Working with data in Python 3+ with pandas. It seems like there should be an easy way to check if two columns have a one-to-one relationship (regardless of column type), but I'm struggling to think of the best way to do this.

Example of expected output:

```
A    B     C
0    'a'   'apple'
1    'b'   'banana'
2    'c'   'apple'
```

A & B are one-to-one? TRUE

A & C are one-to-one? FALSE

B & C are one-to-one? FALSE

Comment: what is A&B are one to one? what is the logic behind this, could you explain little more

Comment: Can you please tell, is that A and B are values or column names ? Seems confusing

Comment: One-to-one is a commonly used term to talk about the relationship between two data objects in a database. They are one-to-one if there is a unique relationship between values. In the above case, A and B are 1:1 because 0 always corresponds to 'a', 1 always corresponds to 'b', etc. And yes, A, B and C are column names. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-one_(data_model)

Comment: For my work it would also be useful to know this in a non-reciprocal way. For example, it is okay that different A values map to a particular C value, but I don't want any single A value to map to multiple C values. I don't need a 1:1 correspondence, but the direction is important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, you can create your own function to check it:

```
def isOneToOne(df, col1, col2):
    first = df.groupby(col1)[col2].count().max()
    second = df.groupby(col2)[col1].count().max()
    return first + second == 2

isOneToOne(df, 'A', 'B')
#True
isOneToOne(df, 'A', 'C')
#False
isOneToOne(df, 'B', 'C')
#False
```

In case you data is more like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 0],
                   'C': ["'apple'", "'banana'", "'apple'", "'apple'"],
                   'B': ["'a'", "'b'", "'c'", "'a'"]})
df
#   A    B         C
#0  0  'a'   'apple'
#1  1  'b'  'banana'
#2  2  'c'   'apple'
#3  0  'a'   'apple'
```

Then you can use:

```
def isOneToOne(df, col1, col2):
    first = df.drop_duplicates([col1, col2]).groupby(col1)[col2].count().max()
    second = df.drop_duplicates([col1, col2]).groupby(col2)[col1].count().max()
    return first + second == 2
```

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick. You even caught an edge case I didn't think of. The second solution (with duplicates removed) works on my data. Thanks again!

Comment: Rather than adding drop_duplicates, I changed `.count()` to `.nunique()`.

Answer (score 9):

```
df.groupby(col1)[col2]\
  .apply(lambda x: x.nunique() == 1)\
  .all()
```

should work fine if you want a true or false answer.

A nice way to visualize the relationship between two columns with discrete / categorical values (in case you are using Jupyter notebook) is :

```
df.groupby([col1, col2])\
  .apply(lambda x : x.count())\
  .iloc[:,0]\
  .unstack()\
  .fillna(0)
```

This matrix will tell you the correspondence between the column values in the two columns.

In case of a one-to-one relationship there will be only one non-zero value per row in the matrix.

Answer (score 5):

```
df.groupby('A').B.nunique().max()==1 #Output: True

df.groupby('B').C.nunique().max()==1 #Output: False
```

Within each value in [groupby column], count the number of unique values in [other column], then check that the maximum for all such counts is one

Comment: this is a much nicer answer

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution (only two or three lines of codes) to check for **any number of columns** to see whether they are one to one match (duplicated matches are allowed, see the example bellow).

```py
cols = ['A', 'B'] # or any number of columns ['A', 'B', 'C']
res = df.groupby(cols).count()
uniqueness = [res.index.get_level_values(i).is_unique 
              for i in range(res.index.nlevels)]
all(uniqueness)
```

---

Let's make it a function and add some docs:

```py
def is_one_to_one(df, cols):
    """Check whether any number of columns are one-to-one match.

    df: a pandas.DataFrame
    cols: must be a list of columns names

    Duplicated matches are allowed:
        a - 1
        b - 2
        b - 2
        c - 3
    (This two cols will return True)
    """
    if len(cols) == 1:
        return True
        # You can define you own rules for 1 column check, Or forbid it

    # MAIN THINGs: for 2 or more columns check!
    res = df.groupby(cols).count()
    # The count number info is actually bootless.
    # What maters here is the grouped *MultiIndex*
    # and its uniqueness in each level
    uniqueness = [res.index.get_level_values(i).is_unique
                  for i in range(res.index.nlevels)]
    return all(uniqueness)
```

By using this function, you can do the one-to-one match check:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 2, 0],
                   'B': ["'a'", "'b'", "'c'", "'a'"],
                   'C': ["'apple'", "'banana'", "'apple'", "'apple'"],})

is_one_to_one(df, ['A', 'B'])
is_one_to_one(df, ['A', 'C'])
is_one_to_one(df, ['A', 'B', 'C'])
# Outputs:
# True
# False
# False
```

Comment: I appreciate this answer providing a generalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

one way to solve this ,

```
df['A to B']=df.groupby('B')['A'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()==1)
df['A to C']=df.groupby('C')['A'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()==1)
df['B to C']=df.groupby('C')['B'].transform(lambda x:x.nunique()==1)
```

Output:

```
   A  B       C  A to B  A to C  B to C
0  0  a   apple    True   False   False
1  1  b  banana    True    True    True
2  2  c   apple    True   False   False
```

To check column by column:

```
print (df['A to B']==True).all()
print (df['A to C']==True).all()
print (df['B to C']==True).all()

True
False
False
```

Comment: @user1895076 - did you try this one?